# MYSQL: Query only working with one value?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a mysql query that looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users
          JOIN signup ON users.uid = signup.uid
          JOIN jobs ON users.category_id = jobs.id
          JOIN lclasses ON users.class = lclasses.class_id
          JOIN degrees ON users.degree_id = degrees.degree_id
          JOIN trades ON users.trade_id = trades.trade_id
          JOIN tradestatuses ON users.trade_status = tradestatuses.status_id
          WHERE users.uid='{$id}' LIMIT 1";
```

If $id = 8, then my query returns properly. If I try any other id that's in my database, I get an empty result set.

I tested the query in phpMyAdmin and get the same result. No errors in the query when I use the different numbers, just an empty result set yet I can look at the row right in the Browse section. Is my table corrupted? Anybody had anything like that ever happen to them?

Comment: ids are straight up numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,etc...

Comment: Are there any null values in any of the tables? `JOIN` is an inner join, so null can screw stuff up.

Comment: Change your JOINs to LEFT JOINs and look for unexpected NULLs in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty result set is an empty result set.

Since they are all *INNER* JOINS, *any one* of the joins could be "linking to nothing" (and thus resulting an empty result set). It is impossible to say more without careful inspection of the data. I would consider breaking the query down into parts to see which part "doesn't work".

Happy coding.

---

Helpful advice from mu's post comment:

> > Change your JOINs to LEFT JOINs and look for unexpected NULLs in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, problem is in a query logic. To check it, please supply description of tables and what are expected results. A good practical way to find an error is commenting of other joins.
Start from

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE users.uid='{$id}' 
LIMIT 1
```

And then add find join which cut the records